# Question on printing in regards to a solution

Tags: python

I am not sure if this is a HOF or not, its a function within a function so I assume HOF.

```
def count_cond(condition):
    """Returns a function with one parameter N that counts all the numbers from
    1 to N that satisfy the two-argument predicate function Condition, where
    the first argument for Condition is N and the second argument is the
    number from 1 to N.

    >>> count_factors = count_cond(lambda n, i: n % i == 0)
    >>> count_factors(2)   # 1, 2
    2
    >>> count_factors(4)   # 1, 2, 4
    3
    >>> count_factors(12)  # 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12
    6

    >>> is_prime = lambda n, i: count_factors(i) == 2
    >>> count_primes = count_cond(is_prime)
    >>> count_primes(2)    # 2
    1
    >>> count_primes(3)    # 2, 3
    2
    >>> count_primes(4)    # 2, 3
    2
    >>> count_primes(5)    # 2, 3, 5
    3
    >>> count_primes(20)   # 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19
    8
    """
    def counts(n):
        i = 1
        counter = 0
        while i <= n:
            if (n % i == 0):
                counter += 1
            i += 1
        return counter

    return counts
```

When I run said code I get `expected 3 but got 4`

I am just trying to figure out how to print this out, so I can put it in python tutor to see where 4 is coming from etc.

I was told to put:

```
print(count_cond(3)())
```

or

```
result = count_cond(3)
print(result())
```

But it doesnt run anything

Comment: What do you mean by "HOF"?

Comment: Even a prime number is divisible by 1. `i` should start at `2`.

Comment: @ScottHunter higher order function

Comment: The argument to `count_cond` needs to be a function, as in your documentation examples ("...the two-argument predicate function Condition").  You are passing a number instead.

Comment: `count_primes` does not behave as the documentation says it should.

Comment: You never use `condition` anywhere. `if (n % i == 0):` should be `if condition(n):`

Comment: @barmar I am still trying to solve it, what I was trying to achieve was to be able to put it in python tutor so i could see line by line but whenever i try to call one of the functions I get an error.... My hopes was if i put it in the tutor then i could see where its producing 4 when its expecting three adn then reverse engineer that to solve the problem! 

But I will add the condition